# Creating persistent android views programmatically

Tags: android, view, persistent

I have an application that can read some formatted data XML/JSON and builds views and listeners from this. Currently I am doing this in `onCreate`, but I don't want this to happen every time the app is opened, I'd rather do it only on first launch and the UI persisted or better still somehow do it when compiling/building the app from eclipse.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean when you say views and listeners.  Is this essentially doing code generation?

Comment: You could dump all the UI information into a private file and "rebuild" it in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways you could do that. You could try saving the data to a database and create views from this data whenever app opens and run a thread to download new data to database which refreshes view upon completing download. You could also give the option to update the data to user so he could update it as and when he wants it.

To use data only on compiling, it could be a big problem. First of all, you would not be able to refresh the data any time! This data would make for a static app. If you still want to go forwards, you could either Hard code the in your code or write the data in a .txt file and read it from the file every time app opens!

Comment: What I ended up doing was building my layout/res/drawables xml with a seperate java application ahead of time, on first launch i make a application scope hashtable of all my views int representation to their json object and split my json up by activity and add events to the activities when they are run, it's dynamic because i'm tracking changes to my layout in the app scope hash tables performance so far is ok, i know this might not be the best way but it works for me.

Comment: Well, the best way is always the one which works for you! Happy to help anyway. :)